# Intersystem's ENSEMBLE JDBC SQL Gateway example

Tags: intersystems-ensemble

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle DB from an Ensemble 2010 machine, on a server that i can only access remotely.
So, I first tried it locally: I installed the same Ensemble 2010 with Oracle 10g and Created a new JDBC Gateway Connection which seems to work (at least it gives a message of "connection successful")
When I try to do the same on the remote Ensemble machine, it gives an error. This remote machine has to connect to an Oracle 7.3.4
I made a simple java class and made it run on the remote server and it could connect to Oracle
I also went to the log configuration, but it says nothing! just a few numbers and lines that look very cryptic.

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The best advice in this situation is to contact WRC at support@intersystems.com, because there is really not enough information in your question to suggest anything. Good idea is to post at least OS names of all servers and these cryptic numbers/errors. Also try to connect via ODBC not JDBC (maybe Java is not configured properly on a remote server). Try to use the same ODBC/JDBC source from Ensemble and from other programs on remote machine.